# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: horizontal variant?

Tags: nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The Kolmogorov Smirnov test is based on the maximum **vertical** distance between the ECDFs of two provided samples.

Is there a variant that checks the maximum **horizontal** distance?

Comment: What would the $H_{0}$ of this test mean substantively speaking?

Comment: The same as in Kolmogorov-Smirnov: the samples are drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: There's an issue of scale here - the vertical scale is a probability between 0 and 1, the horizontal distance depends upon choice of units.

Comment: Ricky, it is not at all clear to me that the null hypothesis would be "the same as" the K-S test, particularly when the math of what you propose diverges. (Of course whether something is "clear to me" may not matter... I'm just some jerk on the Internet. :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess as to why people don't use it: if you have a test that looks at horizontal distance it won't be distribution-free (at least not without some modification*).

Consider a continuous cdf and an ecdf plotted on the same axes with the KS-statistic marked in at the point of greatest vertical distance between them.

Note that a completely monotonic transformation of the x-axis will change the horizontal scale but leave the vertical distances unchanged. It's this feature that in essence makes the K-S test work the same for every fully-specified continuous distribution (since you can convert between them by exactly such a transformation).

But if you measure horizontal distance, every non-identity transform is going to change the distribution of horizontal distances.

* It might work if you convert everything back to standard uniform and then measure horizontal distance, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.